# Where to put the custom job assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I would like my scheduler to run a custom job I have defined. Let us say the job is the same as the Quartz.Net documentation has exemplified:

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
    .Build();
```

I already have the code for the job class. I am running Quartz.Net as a Windows service. I have added my job class to my Quartz server and it recognises it. But I am controlling my server from a separate application. That means I use `GetScheduler()` to get an instance of the service and then would like to add and remove `HelloJobs` from it. Do I need to create an assembly of my job and put it inside my Windows application's `bin` folder as well?

The down side to this is that every time I do a small change on my job, I would have to create a new `DLL` for it and place it inside my calling application.

Is there a way I could avoid creating the `DLL` every time for my Windows application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into the source code, it looks like the app indeed needs to know the job type, which will also need to implement IJob (you probably know this already). There is default constructor on JobBuilder but all it does is create an empty instance.

I don't think there's anything wrong with that as you can easily have your jobs on separate assemblies from your windows service and add references to them on both the service and the windows app. Since the app only needs the name of the job type you will not need to redeploy/make any changes to it **unless** the name of the type changes.

Comment: No I don't find it necessary and as I said I would like to avoid it. But if I am to create a new HelloJob on my application, how does my application know what a HelloJob is? I mean the first line of both of our codes?

Comment: Your wouldn't be able to create a new HelloJob as such. I assume you want to do this so you can pass settings to HelloJob?

Comment: I don't quite get you by "pass settings to HelloJob". How can I create a HelloJob on my application then? I mean the easiest way of course.

Comment: Should I add JobListeners and TriggerListeners on my service?

Comment: These are generally for tracking job/trigger status. Started/finished etc. If you have an assembly called HelloJob on your service and want to provide input to it from your windows app, then you would generally retrieve it as a job from the scheduler as shown above (assuming it exists in your jobstore) and then use the JobDataMap property on the job to provide the input (what I meant by settings). That is the only conception your app would have of the job.

Comment: That's what I want to do. But as soon as I add the line JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>() on my application, isn't it going to ask "Hey what is this?"

Comment: Sorry you're right- I didn't notice the concrete type on the constructor. Let me update my answer.